# Solar retrofit controller has common positive. Will it damage the solar panel?

Tags: solar-cell, inverter

I saw a demonstration of a solar retrofit controller, which is an add-on to a power inverter to help it use solar power. The back panel shows that it has different terminals for the negative wires of the solar panel and the battery but has a common terminal for the positive wires of both. Is this normal? If the negatives are not connected to a common ground inside the controller, will the solar panel be protected from the battery (back flow) and vice versa (unregulated high panel voltage)?

Update: I did not want to name the product but it is in [this link](https://www.zunsolar.com/products/SMU/5f196c184b15295d154fd61f). Their video is at [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKrWL-gXGsw). Note that the puny wire is reserved for positive but the negatives are thick wires.

[image: Photo of the solar retrofit controller]

Comment: I did not see it, can you give us information, links, make and model information. Without more information I cannot answer your questions.

Comment: Added video and product page links

Comment: It's likely based on a low side switch, either for PWM control or for protection or both. Then the puny +ve wire doesn't have to carry significant current. I can't comment on that unit but the basic idea seems sound enough.

Comment: I tried your links they were extremely slow and never finished. What current is going through this wire, that will determine if it is large enough.

Comment: The purpose of a solar charge controller is to avoid a direct connection between the battery and the solar panel - to prevent back flow and high panel voltage. This controller requires it by having a common positive.